# Using ActiveRecord Module within non ActiveRecord class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, activerecord, enums, module

I have some trouble with an non ActiveRecord class.

I have a simple class like:

```
class Factory

end
```

without the mother class "ActiveRecord::Base".

Now I'm trying to use enums from ActiveRecord::Enum Module so I'm using:

```
include ActiveRecord::Enum
```

but when I call

```
enum value: [:Info, :Test]
```

I get following error message:

```
undefined method `enum' for JavaFactory:Class
```

How can I use the enum from the included Module now?

Thank you!

Best regards
Kumaro

Comment: You have a typo. inlcude should be include

Comment: Oh sorry. It is just wrong here ^^. thx for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `extend` your class with the `ActiveRecord::Enum`, not `include` it, since the receiver of method `enum` is the class itself, not it's instances.

Changing

```
include ActiveRecord::Enum
```

to

```
extend ActiveRecord::Enum
```

should fix the current exception (although I suggest you to go through [the documentation on ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), since I have no idea how are you going to (according to my knowledge you can't) use it with non-database backed model).

Comment: Ah okay thats sounds good but now I get following error: "undefined method `dangerous_class_method?' Factory:Class"

Comment: It might be the next issue, which I don't know about yet. You could post it as a separate question I think

Comment: Thanks. Its very strange because I get no results if I google this error message. I think I should open a new question post.